# find out the class type inside the class and its children

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

Lets say I have the class

```
template<typename PointT>
class Parent {
  public:
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<Parent<PointT> > Ptr;

  inline Ptr
  makeShared ()
  {
    return Ptr (new Parent<PointT> (*this));
  }
};

template<typename PointT>
class Child : public Parent {
  public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Child<PointT> > Ptr;
};
```

Now what I'd like to rewrite the definition of Ptr and makeShared() to be generic, so that calling makeShared() from child class(es) instances would yield a pointer to the child class not the parent

To make it more clear calling makeShared() on any class inheriting Parent would give a pointer to an instance of that inheriting class. and calling make shared() on the parent class would give a pointer to an instance of Parent class 
Any ideas?

Comment: A pointer to the base class will work for a polymorphic design. Alternately, look up the abstract factory pattern it may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

CRTP will work here:

```
template<typename Child>
class Parent {
  public:
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<Child> Ptr;

  inline Ptr
  makeShared ()
  {
    return Ptr (new Child(*static_cast<Child *>(this)));
  }
};

template<typename PointT>
class Child : public Parent<Child> {
};
```

Note that `makeShared` is a fairly confusing name as it could be confused with [`shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) (in C++11 and Boost).  A more typical name for your method is `clone`.

Comment: yes but this is not generic at all. if I call makeshared from Parent, I expect to get a pointer to parent instance, same goes for Child, same goes for Child2, etc.. so doing a specialization on the parent class with a certain child class won't help

Comment: @MoatazElmasry are you sure that's what you want? That would imply slicing, unless you make the function virtual.

Comment: btw I like the name makeShared(). it tells me that it makes a shared pointer out of the current class instance. the rest follows...

Comment: I updated the code a bit. the Ptr returned by the makeShared() from child class should be naturally a pointer to the child class itself. so Ptr and makeShared() definitions are dependant on the class type, Parent/child