# how can C++ base class know know which class has derived from it?

Tags: c++, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [find out the class type inside the class and its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077471/find-out-the-class-type-inside-the-class-and-its-children)

I have a method to invoke within a base class, a new requirement has arisen and now within this method i need to know which sub class it has been derived from, do you guys happen to know if this is possible?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the question. Some example?

Comment: Do you mean which subclass it was *invoked* from?

Comment: You might want to see 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077471/find-out-the-class-type-inside-the-class-and-its-children

Comment: i have a base class and from this other classes are derived, now when a method within this class is called i need to know from which class this base class was derived from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to illustrate the idea behind PeteBecker's answer:

```
#include <cstdio>    

class Base {

public:

    virtual char const * type () const = 0;

};

class DerivedA : public Base {

public:

    char const * type () const
    {
        return "A";
    }

};


class DerivedB : public Base{

public:

    char const * type () const
    {
        return "B";
    }

};

int main ()
{
    Base * a = new DerivedA();
    Base * b = new DerivedB();

    fprintf(stderr, "a has type '%s'\n", a->type());
    fprintf(stderr, "b has type '%s'\n", b->type()); 

    delete a;
    delete b;

    return 0;
}
```

Have a look at http://ideone.com/HaAnY for the output.

Answer (score 8):

That's what virtual functions are for. Overriding a virtual function in the derived class means that the base class doesn't have to know anything about derived types. In general, if a base class has to know about derived classes it reflects a design mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) to find that out:

```
DerivedClass *p = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass*>(this);
if (p != null) { ...use p... }
```

You probably don't want to do this, though.  There is almost always a better way using overridden methods of the base class.

Comment: That wouldn't work if deriving classes are loaded during runtime.

Comment: True, you need to know what the set of possible subclasses is at compile time.  Or at least the ones that require non-default behavior.

Comment: @MarcusRiemer - while it's possible to imagine perverse factoring into multiple libraries, in any reasonable case, if an object of the derived type exists, then the code and data structures for the derived type will have been loaded. So this only doesn't work if the programmer goes out of his way to make it fail.

Comment: But you couldn't cast to that type at **compile** time.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be possible to find out in a reliable way! Think about shared libraries that are loaded at runtime, how would you react to something like this?

When taking the approach in the answer given above

```
DerivedClass *p = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass*>(this);
if (p != null) { ...use p... }
```

You wouldn't be able to react for cases where the deriving class is not known at compile time, as you don't know their type.

C++ does not have a strong notion of reflection, so I would answer with "no".

Comment: Whats the downvote for? The title clearly states "how can C++ base class know know which class has derived from it?" and thats what I have answered.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but there are 2 other answers showing 2 different ways of doing what you say is impossible. That might have something to do with it.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter (but close), but if a member function of the base class was called on an object of a derived type, then the object of the derived type exists, so its code has to have been loaded, and there's no issue with late loading of shared libraries.

Comment: @ praetorian: They actually don't. One answer is unrelated and the other doesn't take runtime loading into account.

Comment: @PeteBecker But you cant find that out using RTTI or related mechanisms.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect the problem I saw. Its not entirely impossible, but there are corner cases you can't catch.

Comment: You *could* use `typeid(this).name()` and branch on the class name.  That would handle dynamically loaded subclasses.  (Caveat: the loaded classes probably need to be compiled with RTTI.  And you're dumb if you do this, overloading is a much better way.)

Comment: Then you would still need to know the class name at compile time. I simply wanted to emphasise the corner cases, that make this approach rather tedious (as you mentioned). I simply didn't understand the downvote and am somehow childish currently ;)